# Nginx and complex URI rewrites

Tags: rewrite, rewritecond

I'm having problem with getting logic behind Nginx rewrites. Are they supposed to be in server or location directive?

I need to rewrite one long and scary URL to another. Is there anyone who can help or at least show me resources to get this done?

Example:

I need to redirect this: 
http://www.example.com/products.asp?category=Games&product=Glide%20SX%202012%20-%20%20Super%20Partno&utm_source=wcl-ht

into this: 
http://www.example.com/games/2xu-glid/

Is this even possible?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: "Context: server, location, if". So it can be both in server and location. The ones are in server are proceeded first.

Comment: This is such a complex rewrite that I would perform it inside the `products.asp` script. It requires several `if` statements when performed in nginx, because nginx `rewrite` directive doesn't process query arguments.

Answer (score 0):

## 1. Handling arguments

Despite what Tero Kilkanen says, nginx is perfectly capable of handling arguments: this is done by using the [`args`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_args) and [`arg_`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_arg_) variables from the core module.

## 2. `rewrite` context

As Glueon pointed out, [`rewrite`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) is usable in `server`, `location` and `if` contexts, as the documentation states.

`if` is to be avoided at all costs, so I won't be going inot details about it here.

Now should you use `rewrite` in `server` or `location`?

### In `server`

Blocks of `rewrite`s will be considered sequentially, and the first matching will be used. **Your configuration thus depends on the order of directives**, which is bad (it is one of the things which are wrong with Apache).

See for yourself:

```
rewrite ^/(?<category>[^/]+)/(?<product>[^/]+) /products.asp?category=$category&product=$product&utm_source=wcl-ht last;
rewrite ^/games/(?<product>[^/]+) /games.asp?product=$product&utm_source=wcl-ht last;
```

will redirect to `products.asp, while`

```
rewrite ^/games/(?<product>[^/]+) /games.asp?product=$product&utm_source=wcl-ht last;
rewrite ^/(?<category>[^/]+)/(?<product>[^/]+) /products.asp?category=$category&product=$product&utm_source=wcl-ht last;
```

will redirect to `games.asp`.

According to best practices, it is better to enclose regular expression routing directives (`rewrite`, but also regex `location`) inside prefix locations.

### In `location`

You could rewrite the previous examples as

```
location /games {
    rewrite ^/games/(?<product>[^/]+) /games.asp?product=$product&utm_source=wcl-ht;
}

location / {
    rewrite ^/(?<category>[^/]+)/(?<product>[^/]+) /products.asp?category=$category&product=$product&utm_source=wcl-ht;
}
```

Using prefix locations, you ensure that **whatever ordering you use, the result will *always* be the same**.

## 3. Minimal configuration

Here is a minimal configuration aiming in the direction of what you wish.

There is no obvious translation rule from 2xu-glid to Glide%20SX%202012%20-%20%20Super%20Partno. If that depends on non-trivial conditions and complex checks, it is probably better to use scripting to do it. Using `if` inside nginx is dangerous without knowing what you do and could wreak havoc. You can also use a bunch of nested locations to split your translation rules into modular units.

Note that I use a single rewrite here, so it does not need a flag nor does it need to be enclosed in a location. That is because there is only a signle way that configuration might be resolved.

*Also note the use of `return` at the end to ensure no file is ever tried to be served (the default behavior, when no suitable location is found, is to try to serve either a file or `index.html from the requested directory`, depending on whether the URI ends with `/`). Since no `root` is defined, the default internally set would have been used.*

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    default_type  text/html;

    server {
        listen       80;

        rewrite ^/(?<category>[^/]+)/(?<product>[^/]+) /products.asp?category=$category&product=$product&utm_source=wcl-ht last;

        location /products.asp {
            internal;
            return 200 "Arguments: $args<br />arg_category: $arg_category<br />arg_product: $arg_product<br />arg_utm_source: $arg_utm_source";
        }

        return 404;
    }
}
```